# emacs: how to set users current folder?

Tags: macos, emacs

when I start emacs in Mac at Dock, I found the default open folder is / ,not the ~/ , how do I change back to ~/ ?
In old days ,its right. I add SSD these day ,and clone all my file to ssd set is as start disk.I don't know that is reason or not.

I start emacs at Dock. when start emacs , I enter: "c-x c-f ", emacs tip:" find file: /", which is not my want, but ' find file : ~/'.

and echo $HOME in terminal is correct: /Users/me

### when start emacs in terminal , it works.

finally: I download a new version and install ,it can work well. its awsome

Comment: What does `echo $HOME` say?

Comment: Is Emacs being started with your user's uid?

Comment: I start emacs with mouse. <= =>

Comment: C-h v "default-direcotry". If you started emacs from finder than you'd probably want a GUI version of Emacs. See http://emacsformacosx.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `$HOME` environment variable (outside Emacs), if it is not set.

You can put `(setq-default default-directory "~/")` in your init file.

You say that you invoke Emacs using the mouse.  What does that mean, exactly?

I'm not familiar with starting Emacs on the Mac, but perhaps there is a "start in" directory specified for the shortcut or whatever that you use with the mouse.

For example, on MS Windows, you can create a desktop (or a menu) shortcut that you can use to start Emacs, and in the definition of that shortcut you can specify which directory you want Emacs to start in. Perhaps something similar exists for a Mac.

Finally, read this doc: `C-h r g entering emacs`.

Comment: I start emacs at Dock.and I found  I can't start in terminal such: 'emacs & ' , must 'sudo emacs &' or 'emacs '

Comment: I found that `(setq-default default-directory "~/")` didn't work for me, but `(setq default-directory "~/")` did the trick. GNU Emacs v27.1 on macOS Catalina

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default directory this way: `(setq default-directory "~/")`

Comment: Unclear what the problem is: does Emacs have the wrong default directory?  I'm not 100% familiar with OSX's directory structure, but `/` is the root directory and your user directory should be something like `/home/dien/` (or whatever your user ID is in place of `dien`).  You can find out by entering `echo $HOME` in a terminal as Mischa suggested above.